# Can I render the response of the success block of ajax to the ejs file?

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, ejs

I have comparison.ejs file. I want to parse the response in this file.

Can I redirect to the comparison.ejs file in WebServer folder from the some.ajax file in public folder.

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
$(".button4").click(function(){
var a="",b="",c="",d="";
if(($('#out1').css('display') == 'block') || ($('#out2').css('display') == 'block') || ($('#out3').css('display') == 'block') || ($('#out4').css('display') == 'block'))
{
  if($('#out1').css('display') == 'block')
  {
    a = $('#cd1').attr('class');
    // alert(a);
  }
  if($('#out2').css('display') == 'block')
  {
    b = $('#cd2').attr('class');
    // alert(b);
  }
  if($('#out3').css('display') == 'block')
  {
    c = $('#cd3').attr('class');
    // alert(c);
  }
  if($('#out4').css('display') == 'block')
  {
    d = $('#cd4').attr('class');
    // alert(d);
  }
  // alert(a+" "+b+" "+c+" "+d);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/compItems',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(
      {
        dat1: a,
        dat2: b,
        dat3: c,
        dat4: d
      }
    ),
    success: function(response)
    {
      // document.write(response);
      var renderedData = new EJS({url:'../../Webserver/views/comparison.ejs'}).render({data:response});
      alert("Here");
      document.write(renderedData);
      // $('.contact').html(renderedData);
    }
  });
}
else {
  alert("Please select minimum one product");
}
});
}
```

response are giving me the desired output. Now I want to rendered this response to the comparison.ejs file.

is it possible to do that? or I can create ejs through jquery inside success block.

In above code I will call this ajax code from index.ejs file in views folder.

Comment: the ajax and frontend has no knowledge that an ejs file even exists. I don't understand what you're asking. ejs: backend. ajax: frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean that you want to show response if the process has completed? You can use [flash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flash) to show notification. 
for example

```
req.flash('message_err', "password didn't match");
```

then pass it in render function

```
res.render('index/login', {message_err: req.flash('message_err')});
```

and print the `{{message_err}}` in the view